# Template Instantiation for Library Use

Tags: c++, templates

I'm building an image processing library in C++(0x) which relies heavily upon templates, and I'm worried about the effect these templates will have on users' compilation times.  For example, I have defined my image class as ns::Image, and I have several pixel types such as ns::PixRGB, ns::PixRGBA, ns::PixHSV, etc...

I will also many image processing functions, e.g.

```
template<class T, class S>
  void ns::drawCircle(ns::Image<T> & img, S color, ns::Circle);
```

Now, I know that 95% of users will just want to call `ns::drawCircle<PixRGB<byte>, PixRGB<byte>>(...)`, so I would like to explicitly instantiate just *some* combinations of these types of functions while still allowing the compiler to custom compile anything that I haven't specified.  Doing so will allow me to keep the compilation speed of a shared library and the flexibility of a header-only library.

Is this type of thing possible, and if so what is the syntax?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is called an explicit instantiation.  In a header file, somewhere after the `ns::drawCircle<T,S>` function template has been defined:

```
namespace ns {
    extern template void drawCircle<>(
        Image<PixRGB<byte> >& img, PixRGB<byte> color, Circle);
}
```

In a *.cpp file in your library:

```
namespace ns {
    template void drawCircle<>(
        Image<PixRGB<byte> >& img, PixRGB<byte> color, Circle);
}
```